# Can UIButton background image support Dynamic Type?

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton, accessibility, dynamic-type-feature

After watching [this talk](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2017/245/) I would like to support Dynamic Type in my app. It's easy for labels, but what about UIButton with an image set as a background? Image is in pdf, single scale and Preserve Vector Data. UIButton has Accessibility > Adjusts Image Size checkmark on but still it doesn't work. I haven't set any constraint for size for that button.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The background image is **scaled to fill the bounds** of a UIButton.

The only way to enlarge this kind of image is by using the `Dynamic Type` and change the size as you noticed in the [WWDC video](http://a11y-guidelines.orange.com/mobile_EN/dev-ios-wwdc-17245.html) you watched.

However, it's still possible to scale the image *(not the background)* and the font of your button using the text styles :

```
myButton.titleLabel?.adjustsFontForContentSizeCategory = true
myButton.adjustsImageSizeForAccessibilityContentSizeCategory = true
```

Finally, **the background image only adjusts its size to the bounds of its button according to the accessibility `Dynamic Type` sizes used for its title label**.

Besides, if you can't use the Dynamic Type in this case, you could take a look at the [`Large Content Viewer`](http://a11y-guidelines.orange.com/mobile_EN/dev-ios-wwdc-19261.html) if need be ⟹ **the `UILargeContentViewerItem` protocol** is an **iOS 13 new feature** that shows the same HUD that's shown for standard bar items.